# Excel - Ignore blank cells in multiplication calculation

Tags: excel, equation

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that spits out a calculation based on a few simple inputs from a user.

What i need to be able to allow users to do is add as many element rows as they want. Then complete the number of variants. The Total cell then sums each row for the user.

I then multiply each of the individual Totals together to come to the Total Experiences cell.

However, when i set Total Experiences cell to include Total cells beyond H that have no value this results in the calculation returning a 0.

Ideally i need the calculation in the Total Experiences cell to ignore those blank cells without each individual user having to manually select the cells in Total to include in the calculation.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Cell breakdown

Column A: Element
Column B: Control
Column C: Variant 1
Column D: Variant 2
Column E: Variant 3
Column F: Total

L